# Using Xcode Playground captureValue()

Tags: swift, xcode7-beta3, xcplayground

I'm using Playgrounds in Xcode 7.1 (beta 3) but having trouble with the `captureValue()` function:

> captureValue:withIdentifier: Captures a value to be displayed with the
>   specified identifier in the timeline.
>
> Declaration
>
> public func captureValue(value: T, withIdentifier identifier:
>   String)

[— Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/XCPlaygroundModuleRef/XCPlayground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016564-CH1-SW9)

When I call the function, all I get is this:

[image: captureValue]

How do I use captureValue? Or is this a bug in beta 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`captureValue()` displays the value you capture in the Timeline, which is a separate view that shows up in a playground's Assistant Editor. (You can show the Assistant Editor by pressing Command-Option-Return.) What you're showing is the result of the current line, which, since `captureValue()` returns `Void`, is just the `XCPlaygroundPage` itself.

Here's what the Timeline should look like:

[image: Playground Timeline]

Comment: PS: `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = yourUIViewInstance`

Comment: I believe that method is now deprecated

Answer (score 4):

However, if you want to have a nice plot in playground instead of a dump list, you'll need to assign `CaptureValue` in a loop.

```
for var i in 1...12 {
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.captureValue(i*i*i, withIdentifier: "Cube")
}
```

Xcode 7.2

[image: Playground with a nice cube plot from 1 to 12]