# Concise way in swift to display graph view for array values in playground side-bar?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Is there a more concise way in swift to display the graph view for an `Array`'s (or other collection's) values in the playground side-bar, other than manually iterating the values?

Other than:

```
for x in array { x }
```

Answer (score 4):

Only so slightly conciser, but you see the same graph view using `.map`:

```
array.map{ $0 }
```

---

#### Xcode >= 7.3

As described in the follinwg Q&A:

- [Swift Playgrounds: Replacement for captureValue(_:withIdentifier:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305877/swift-playgrounds-replacement-for-capturevalue-withidentifier)

The explicit `captureValue(_:withIdentifier)` approach—as previously covered in this answer as an alternative approach to the Playground-automatically displayed graphs—has been deprecated in Xcode 7.3.

#### Prior to Xcode 7.3

We could previously explicitly display the same graph view in the playground:s timeline (as opposed to the playground:s sidebar) by using `XCPlaygroundPage` method `.captureValue(_:withIdentifier)`

```
import XCPlayground
let array = Array(1...10)
array.map{XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.captureValue($0, withIdentifier: "My numbers")}
```

The identifier `"My numbers"` would serve as a title for the displayed graph in the timeline.

To show the timeline: show the assistant editor (`View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor`).

See also the following thread regarding the (now deprecated) `captureValue(...)` method:

- [Using Xcode Playground captureValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262228/using-xcode-playground-capturevalue)

Comment: `captureValue` seems to be deprecated.

Comment: @MartinR thanks! I'll look into updating this answer to Swift 3 this evening; currently not on OS X.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305877/swift-playgrounds-replacement-for-capturevalue-withidentifier.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, that's sufficient to update this answer.